# Couchbase - bidirectional replication

Tags: replication, couchbase, bidirectional

I'm trying to figure out if the community edition of Couchbase supports bidirectional replication btwn data centers?
I'm reading this: https://www.couchbase.com/products/editions
but I can't see any clear comments about it.

What I'm trying to test / achieve is what's described in the following documentation under the "bidirectional" section. 
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/learn/clusters-and-availability/xdcr-overview.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bidirectional replication just means you have XDCR going from cluster A to B, and another XDCR going from cluster B to A. Since Community Edition includes XDCR, it includes bidirectional replication.